# "borehole" sink edge workflow

Tags: modeling, modifiers, objects, edit-mode

[image]

Here you can see how i cut some holes using the boolean mod.

[image]

My goal is to sink all holes.

I came up with a very step inconvenient procedure on my own but my question is how the pro's would apply this common finish. Thank you for the wisdom!

Comment: As the answer suggests, since you're already using the Boolean modifier, why not make the cutter so that it gives the desired result? You're not working in the real world where you have to take one step after another ;) But now that you've already got the holes, you could select the edges and bevel them with the Bevel tool in Edit mode (Ctrl + B) using one segment.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the boolean modifier already, you could just adjust your cutter like this:

[image]

Of course, with more subdivisions the result will look much smoother.

Result:

[image]